# DirectX 11のコードがVisual Studioでコンパイルできない

Tags: visual-studio, directx

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019でC++で、
インターネット上にあったdirectx11のコードをコピペしコンパイルして実行しようとしたら。
下のアドレスにある画像のコンソール画面がでて終了します。
どうしたらDirectxの実行結果が見れますか？

https://d.kuku.lu/1efc206a45
https://f.easyuploader.app/eu-prd/upload/20200606170521_3055744b687337764f58.png

解決しました。
プロジェクト作り直したら動きました。
コンソールアプリの設定で作っていたようです。
ごめんなさい。

Comment: https://f.easyuploader.app/eu-prd/upload/20200606170521_3055744b687337764f58.png

Comment: 画面から推測されるキーワードからすると、このページ [【3Dモデル】モデル描画](https://yttm-work.jp/model_render/model_render_index.html) のこの記事 [FBX SDKのインストール方法と環境設定](https://yttm-work.jp/model_render/model_render_0006.html) くらいから始まるいくつかの記事が参考になるかもしれません。あるいはこの辺の記事とか。[FBX SDK準備編 – ファイルからデータを取得しよう](https://codelabo.com/posts/20200228164918), [【DirectX】FBX SDKの導入](https://qiita.com/Nyarll/items/c653e15a91a1eea94b61), [FBXファイルの読み込み1](https://www.tkng45memo.com/fbxmesh)

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Comment: お疲れさまでした。自己解決された場合、スタック・オーバーフローでは自己回答することができ、また推奨されています。少し時間が経つと自分の回答を承認することもできるようになりますので、お試しくださいませ。

Comment: 単に「ありがとう」だけだと、「コメントを付けてくれて」なのか「おかげで解決しました」なのかが分からないかなと思います。

Comment: >> nekketsuuuなるほど、ありがとうございます。

Comment: >>cubickそうですね、気をつけます。

Answer (score 0):

空のプロジェクトから作成ではうまくいかずコンソール画面が出るのみで、
プロジェクトを作り直しを試み、
Windowsデスクトップウィザードを選択してから空のプロジェクトを選択するとうまくいきました。
https://f.easyuploader.app/eu-prd/upload/20200609210034_78523370583669585a6a.png
https://f.easyuploader.app/eu-prd/upload/20200609210212_514e48495470454c356e.png